# How do I know a Spark join is an efficient copartitioned-input join?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I'm try to optimize a piece of PySpark code by taking advantage of some partitioning strategies, specifically co-partitioning two RDDS, unioning them, and calling a reduce operation on them (it's more complicated than that, but that's a good initial model).

Looking at the diagram in:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [reactivesoftware.pl](http://reactivesoftware.pl/spark/img/rdd_dependency.png))</sub>

the co-partition join is very efficient and skinny. My question is, how do I know my join/reduce is co-partitioned correctly? What statistics should I see on the Spark application UI? What performance improvements should I expect to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When data is not properly co-partitioned in Spark, the system has to perform a shuffle (i.e. move the data to a new temporary partition to create the necessary join to perform the transformation.)

So the key difference between the two is the amount of shuffle read and write time i.e. for narrow dependencies you should see minimal read and zero write, whereas for wide dependencies you would see a significant shuffle write. You can view shuffle read and write statistics in the stage details of the Spark UI.

You really see two performance gains from eliminating wide dependencies:

- Shuffles themselves take up significant IO and network resources.
- By having a wide dependency chain, shuffle operations are often the bottleneck for other operations downstream.

And point of clarification: reduce operations always shuffle in order to aggregate the data, so the partitioning strategy only applies to the joins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your comment >"you should see minimal read and zero write" is what I was looking for. For your last point, isn't it true that if the rdd is already partitioned, then a reduceByKey is just a local reduce, which doesn't involve any shuffling?

Comment: @Cam If your partitions contain the complete set of data for a given key, then yes, but for sufficiently large Spark datasets you'll find yourself splitting up a single key's values over multiple partitions (i.e. key "A" might be split over partitions 1, 2, and 3) to gain some parallelism benefits.